# get index of radio in ng-repeat outside of ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use the selected radio as a reference to it's index within its array so that I may add more children in it's sub array (using the selected radio).

So here's what I have:

```
<div class="fakeTableRow"  ng-repeat="parent in listTable">
  <div class="strcutionLeft"></div>
  <!-- parent levels -->
  <div  class="strcutionCRight saInstrcutionTitle"><div class="parentSub1"> <input type="radio" name="levelCheckDat" ng-model="levelChecker" value="{{$index}}">{{parent.name}}</div></div>
</div>
```

And then outside of this (above) there is a button that when pushed calls a function, inside that function I would like a reference to the index the radio is in so I may then drop children inside. Here is my attempt at that:

```
$scope.submitNewSub = function(){
  //get index of radio
  console.log($scope.levelChecker.indexOf($scope.levelChecker));

  // .....continue function with index stored
});
```

My assumption was that the radios are stored in their own scope, however if i simply `log ($scope.levelChecker)` it comes back undefined, so i believe I am thinking about this wrong, I just cannot seem to figure out how.

To be clear, I am just trying to figure out the index (in the ng-repeat) of the selected radio with the model of levelChecker.  Thanks for reading!

Edit: i swapped the value of the button to the {{$index}} to see if i could pull a value off by just calling the scope

Comment: Try passing in parent to your function, then $scope.levelChecker.indexOf(parent);

Comment: I think part of my issue is if i do console.log($scope.levelChecker) it comes back undefined. I assumed it builds it's own scope but I think i have something in the details wrong, thanks!

Comment: I'd place an ng-click on the radio button which calls a function in your scope. You pass the $index as a parameter into that function. Then you've got the index of the selected radio button in your $scope. Would that help?

Comment: Thinking about it a little longer I realise that it sounds a bit like you're thinking jQuery like. Think about modifying your model more than adding behavior based on indexes of radiobuttons and stuff. Do you have the information needed for the sub-radios already in your model? Then flag it by setting some property to 'true' - so pass in 'parent' into your method. If you don't have them - write a method in your scope, pass in the 'parent' and use its id to get more info from some API. Does this make sense?

Comment: I think you are entirely correct, haha. I worked heavily in jquery before this, it's hard to switch gears into this at first. I tried your method of tracking index on click and it seems to work, but I will try and rethink again based on angulars mechanics.